# Group By Timestamp day isn't returning any results

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

HI I have a table which has a time stamp column in it, what i am trying to do is group the results of the table by day and count how many entries exist in that table for that day along with a list of timestamps.

Below is the code i am using it but it isn't returning any results.

```
 $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*),  DAYOFYEAR(timestamp) FROM all_count GROUP BY   DAYOFYEAR(timestamp)";
 $result = mysql_query($query1);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo $row['timestamp'];    
 echo $row['count'];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your result set doesn't contain the columns `timestamp` and `count`. It *does* have `COUNT(*)` and `DAYOFYEAR(timestamp)`. Use aliases get the names you want.

You can modify your query like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count,
  DAYOFYEAR(timestamp) as timestamp
FROM all_count
GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(timestamp)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, that returns one number? is that right, maybe i am going about it the wrong way but what I am trying to do is group the timestamps by day and show how many timestamps there are for that day.

Comment: I think that is what this does. Do you get an error? Make sure you've got error and warnings turned on. The fact that you got _no results_ means you've not got warnings turned on.

Answer (score 0):

because you was not calling it properly, try using allias and call the alias.

change this

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) , DAYOFYEAR(timestamp)
```

to

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as count,  DAYOFYEAR(timestamp) as days
```

and this

```
 echo $row['timestamp'];
```

to

```
echo $row['days'];
```

here should be your code

```
 $query1 = "SELECT `timestamp` ,COUNT(*) as count,  DAYOFYEAR(timestamp) as days FROM all_count GROUP BY    DAYOFYEAR(timestamp)";
  $result = mysql_query($query1);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo $row['days'];    
 echo $row['count'].'<br />';
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't make any difference it's still not returning results

Comment: Thanks, again this just returns a number an nothing else.

Comment: the problem is that you just counting(*) , try to select one column and then count(*) from that column. i gave u example in my updated answer

Comment: Thats what I was trying to do, timestamp is a column and I am trying to count how many entries are in that column per day.

Answer (score 0):

Well technically the answer of @Frits van Campen is correct, however it is very inefficient if you have too many lines in the table. Because, before grouping, every timestamp will be converted to dayofyear, and thats costly.

The proper solution would be to add a new column to the table, say "dayofyear", and calculate the values from the "timestamp" column. Then you can do a basic and and efficient grouping with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM all_count GROUP BY dayofyear
```